# single space as a separator in to_csv in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a text file from pandas dataframe. Two columns are being extracted from dataframe. I want a single space as a separator in txt file. Here is the code I am using.

```
merge_df[['hypothesis_transcript','speaker_tag']].to_csv('/path/hypothesis_tag.txt',sep='\t',index= False)
merge_df[['reference_transcript','speaker_tag']].to_csv('/path/reference_tag.txt',sep='\t',index= False)
```

It generates the output,

```
en dat is dan meestal dat dus   (recreatie-1731)
de uh   (recreatie-1732)
```

But I want a single space only,

```
en dat is dan meestal dat dus (recreatie-1731)
de uh (recreatie-1732)
```

I used `sep = ' '` , which don't give output as expected.

Comment: you can try chain `replace('  ','',regex=True)`  before `to_csv()` method for example `merge_df[['hypothesis_transcript','speaker_tag']].replace('  ','',regex=True).to_csv('/path/hypothesis_tag.txt',sep='\t',index= False)`

Comment: Hi..@AnuragDabas No, it is not giving the desired output

Answer (score 1):

You can try merging both columns into one column separated by a space and the writing just that column to the output.

```
merge_df['Merged_Column'] = merge_df[['hypothesis_transcript','speaker_tag']].astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1)

merge_df['Merged_Column'].to_csv('/path/reference_tag.txt',index= False)
```